# syntax error nested NEXT operator in NuSMV

Tags: model-checking, nusmv, nuxmv

I try to use NuSMV to check my model and here is the code.

[image]

However, when I input `NuSMV kernel.smv` in the shell, it occur an error

```
file kernel.smv: line 16: nested NEXT operators: next(_b)
in definition of next(_cond)
in definition of next(tx.fired) at line 16
```

I'm a newbie in NuSMV model checker, so I could not fix this syntax error. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) out of your image:

```
MODULE trans(cond)
VAR
    fired : boolean;
ASSIGN
    init(fired) := FALSE;
    next(fired) := case
        !next(cond) : TRUE;
        TRUE        : FALSE;
    esac;

MODULE main
VAR
    _b : boolean;
    t  : trans(_cond);
DEFINE
    _cond := (_b != next(_b));
```

Here the *design problem* is exactly what the model checker tells you in the error message:

```
NuSMV > reset; read_model -i t.smv ; go

file t.smv: line 6: nested NEXT operators: next(_b)
in definition of next(_cond)
in definition of next(t.fired) at line 6
```

There is a *double nesting* of the `next()` operator within itself, and this isn't supported as it would require the *execution horizon* to be increased beyond the *current_state + chosen_transition* pair, and know which transition is taken from a future state that is still under construction.

---

**Workaround.**

Let's take the following model, which has the same problem as yours:

```
MODULE main()
VAR
    frst : 0 .. 1;
    scnd : boolean;

ASSIGN
    init(frst) := 0;
    init(scnd) := FALSE;

    next(scnd) := case
        next(middle) : TRUE;
        TRUE         : FALSE;
    esac;

DEFINE
    middle := (frst != next(frst));
```

we want `scnd` to be `true` iff the value of `frst` is going to change amidst the `next()` and the `next(next())` state.

To do so, we can **delay** the *beginning* of the execution trace, so that we can **predict** the future value of `frst` with sufficient advantage.

Let's see it with an example:

```
MODULE main()
VAR
    hidden : 0 .. 1;
    frst   : 0 .. 1;
    scnd   : boolean;

ASSIGN
    init(hidden) := 0;
    init(frst)   := 0;
    init(scnd)   := FALSE;

    next(frst) := hidden; -- frst does not start "changing" arbitrarily
                          -- in the second state, but in the third state

    next(scnd) := case
        predicted : TRUE; -- true iff frst changes value 2 states from now
        TRUE      : FALSE;
    esac;

DEFINE
    middle    := (frst != next(frst));     -- true iff frst changes value
                                           -- from the current state to the
                                           -- next() state
    predicted := (hidden != next(hidden)); -- true iff frst changes value
                                           -- from the next state to the
                                           -- next(next()) state
```